# Does every abelian group of order $16$ have an element of order $4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics

Can we solve this by saying that $|G|=16$ is divisible by $o(g)=4$ and therefore there must exist an element of order $4$ in this group?

Answer (score 4):

No, and in fact the statement is false. The group
$\mathbb{Z}_2^4$ has only elements of order $2$ and $1$.

You are trying to apply Cauchy's theorem, but this only works when the divisor is prime. For example, $2$ is a prime dividing $16$, so Cauchy's theorem tells you there is an element of order $2$, but you can't do the same thing for $4$ because it is not prime.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb Z_2^4$ has only elements of orders $1$ and $2$.